# Display server batch progress on client

Tags: c#, silverlight, ria

I am writing a business application using silverlight 4 including RIA.
The user can start a batch progress on the server by clicking a button.
On the client side, i want to display the progress. How do i do that?

The first idea i had was to create a job manager which creates a job ticket and the client polls regularly for its status / progress.
But is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

You can try COMET Programming, which means you can open a Web Request connection to ASHX file and in that ASHX file you can send Write one line that includes a progress and flush the stream, do not close it till you reach 100%. And on client side you can keep on reading web response till you get 100%, this is better then polling since it only requires one socket connection to server for entire duration and very few bytes of data transfer.